# How to check that the two different pages or url's fired from same browser and ip

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, user-agent

I want to check whether if two of my url are fired from same browser and ip

For this i was using user Agent to check and getting ip from request object, it was fine until Firefox but when it comes to **IE 7+ Versions**, it is weird IE is generating different User Agents for same url's of a web App.

My IE version is 11.0+

For one request i am getting UserAgent like

**Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)**

And for another request:

**Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)**

Actually **i was checking userAgents to perform some bussiness logic based upon userAgents**. so mostly i am looking for a solution based on userAgnets.

**I think feature detection suggested by MSDN docs won't work here.**

Any solution to get same userAgents will be helpful

Comment: Have you ever thought about using cookies?

Comment: i can't use cookies because both are from different domains

Comment: usecase??? @HarshaMV

Comment: @saikiran, what for do you need this? It's a bit weird problem. If you give us more details - maybe a better solution will be suggested.

Comment: this is for some Ad Injection purpose. our clients will validate our clicks based on the click page UserAgent.

Comment: Considering two scenarios when user searches for some key word on my platform i am sending that key word and useragent of my page to my client and i get the response and inject them.

same happens when user clicks on those Ads. client will check the click page UserAgent.

so i can't look for secondary solution because this market runs on UserAgent validation @Kiril

Comment: Even if you're on different domain, you can still use cookies. Just make sure the cookie is set and read on the same domain. A super widespread exemple of this is Google Analytics. On domain A, include a javascript hosted on domain B that sets a cookie. Domain B can access it if the visitor arrives on B. And any other javascript hosted on B but included on A can access it as well.

Comment: Are you limited to client side scripts and html?

Comment: Mine is a browser extension @GerdK and i think there is limitation to client side scripts only.

Comment: our market runs on User Agents so no options are considered ,Bussiness logic needs user agent validation

Comment: IE seems to send shorter user agent to server while `navigator.userAgent` contains the fill user agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first sight it could be easily solved by writing an appropriate RegEx for each browser. Several rules for Browser detection could be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent). Even all (or most of) available user agents could be found [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) (e.g. [for IE](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/), [for Chrome](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/), etc).

So let's say for **IE** browser RegEx could be: `MSIE[^;,)]+`.
For **Chrome** it soulb be `Chrome[^;,)\s]+`, similar to **FireFox**: `Firefox[^;,)\s]+`.

Event more - there's a [third-party API](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/) for user agent parsing.

**BUT** there're tons of browsers and even more browser versions! You'll never be sure that all browsers are covered.

Comment: removing frameworks and tool bars bla bla from UserAgents and sending it is not a good idea??

if we see below string

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)

.NET CLR.. etc are frameworks like this if we can remove them by regular expressions to match exact userAgents.

my idea is to remove all frameworks and toolbar info and matching it as exact userAgent string

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)

Comment: It's very very very hard to remove all "redundant" data from userAgent. E.g. check [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/) how many different information could be added to userAgent in IE. Event if you'll manage to consider all cases - you'll have to keep your logic up-to-date with every new version of IE (event minor version). And that's only for IE! There're so many other browsers...

Comment: present i am facing this issue in IE 8+ versions i can't able to figure a solution by the way you suggested

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use canvas-fingerprinting.

The idea behind this is that every hardware generates unique sparks on the html-canvas.
By saving and analyzing the generated canvas you can reidentify your user.

Example source code:
https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs

---

There is even a testpage here:
http://valve.github.io/fingerprintjs/

Scroll down until you see `Your browser fingerprint`.
Works for me even after changing the UserAgent completely.